# Minimum circumsribed square

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I want to find the minimum circumsribed square of the regular polygon with 2n edge. n is the odd number.I have known the method by observing some simple condition. But how to prove it strictly.

Comment: What is the method you found then? Do you really expect us to repeat your work for you? There was a similar question to yours a few days ago, so you should look there for answers.

Comment: the diagonal of the square conincide with a diagonal of the polygon

Comment: Do you mean the width of the square? If the diagonal of the square coincides with the diagonal of the polygon, then the square does not circumscribe the polygon.

Comment: @IsaacRen actually the diagonal of the square is longer than the polygon

Comment: @IsaacRen the diagonal of the polygon is a little shorter

Comment: As $n$ goes to $\infty$, the polygon approaches a circle. The diagonal of the polygon becomes the diameter of the circle. The square clearly is *inscribed* in the circle, and not the other way around, so for polygons it must be the case as well, for $n$ sufficiently large, right?

Comment: @IsaacRen the diagonal of the square is a little longer

Comment: @IsaacRen thanks you for your answer ，I got it

Answer (score 1):

$n$ is odd; write $n=2p+1$. Let us represent the regular $2n$-gon by the $2n^\text{th}$ roots of unity in $\Bbb C$, i.e. $U:=\{e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{2n}}\mid k\in\{0,\ldots,2n-1\}\}$. We can rotate this polygon by multiplying the roots by $e^{i\alpha}$. Considering various symmetries, we can restrict $\alpha$ to $[0,\frac\pi{2n}]$. The width and height of the rotated polygon (i.e. the width and height of the smallest rectangle which contains the polygon) are then, respectively,
$$\max_{x,y\in U}\Re(xe^{i\alpha}-ye^{i\alpha})\quad\text{and}\quad\max_{x,y\in U}\Im(xe^{i\alpha}-ye^{i\alpha}).$$
We can easily see that these two values are
$$2\cos(\alpha)\quad\text{and}\quad2\cos(\frac\pi{2n}-\alpha),$$
i.e. $(x,y)=(1,-1)$ and $(x,y)=(e^{i\frac{p\pi}n},e^{-i\frac{p\pi}n})$ respectively.

$2\cos$ is nonincreasing on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2n}]$, so to minimize the height and width, it suffices to find $\alpha\in[0,\frac\pi{2n}]$ such that $2\cos(\alpha)=2\cos(\frac\pi{2n}-\alpha)$. We solve and get $\alpha=\frac\pi{4n}$, so the minimal square circumscribing the regular $2n$-gon of diagonal length $2$ is a square of width $2\cos(\frac\pi{4n})$.

Comment: Your result appears to be off by a factor of two. The width of the square will not be greater than the length of the diagonal of the polygon. Also, see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lamCC.jpg) which shows that a diagonal of the polygon lies on a diagonal of the square, which is what the OP meant by "coincides".

Comment: You are right, the $2n$-gon I am working with has diagonal length $2$ (the diameter of the unit circle). And thank you for the drawing! I understand what the OP means now, and I guess it means my proof coincides with their intuition. I edited my answer accordingly.